# How do I change URL when running grunt serve?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using Yeoman and uses grunt serve to look at the application in the browser.

The server starts at http://myhost.com:9000 but I want to know if it's possible to start it at http://myhost.com:9000/hello instead.

I have looked in the documentation to find something to change in the Gruntfile but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the [open](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#open) option you can configure the URL to open in the browser.

```
task: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    open: {
      target: 'http://myhost.com:9000/hello'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What I want to add is the /hello part to the url.